# Bootstrap Popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, onclick, hide, popover

I would like to be able to click outside the popover to make it dissapear.

This code is working well - closes one popover when another is opened and ofcourse when you clcik the button again it goes away.

```
var $visiblePopover;

$('body').on('click', '[rel="popover"]', function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  // check if the one clicked is now shown
  if ($this.data('popover').tip().hasClass('in')) {

// if another was showing, hide it
$visiblePopover && $visiblePopover.popover('hide');

// then store reference to current popover
$visiblePopover = $this;

  } else { // if it was hidden, then nothing must be showing
$visiblePopover = '';
  }
});​
```

I need to keep this current functionality but modify it so that it does the same thing for when you click outside the popover as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it simply by adding:

```
$('html').click(function(e) {
     $('.btn').popover('hide');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moalla/fsRaN/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This little trick is handy if you want to close all other popovers  except the one that has been clicked on:

```
$('.popover').click(function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $('.popover').not(this).popover('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor = Modal
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {


if($visiblePopover && $visiblePopover){
alert("HIDE POPOVER WHEN MODAL IS OPENED")
$visiblePopover && $visiblePopover.popover('hide');
}
        var $this = $(this),
            href = $this.attr('href'),
            $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''))),
            option = $target.data('modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({
                remote: !/#/.test(href) && href
            }, $target.data(), $this.data())
            e.preventDefault()
            $target.modal(option).one('hide', function () {
                $this.focus()

            })
    })
})
```

Comment: This will hide the popover when a modal window is opened, nothing worse than closing a modal to find the popovers still showing.. this fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

add this code at the end of bootstrap.min.js
1) 2 popover were click always hide older popover
2） click outside of popover will hide also

```
$count=0;$(document).click(function(evt){if($count==0){$count++;}else{$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');$count=0;}});$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('click', function(e){$('[data-toggle="popover"]').not(this).popover('hide');$count=0;});
```

Comment: Editing bootstrap.min.js is not a good idea as your changes will get overwritten if the file is updated

Answer (score -1):

When the button to open the Popover is clicked it should gain focus.  When you click away it loses focus and you might be able to catch it with [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) and then use the `popover('hide')`.

Comment: answer no make sense to me nither ,doesnt makes sense to me either